# Scale and Translate SVG when background changes

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, webgl

I am working on an issue where I need to scale and translate an SVG element.  Here is a little background.

An image is drawn to a canvas using Web-GL.  Then a line or circle is drawn on top of the Web-GL canvas as SVG elements.  The WebGL image can then be rotated.

If the image dimensions do not fit in the viewport after rotation, they are scaled properly to fit within the viewport, which changes the dimensions of the image.

After the image has been rotated, the SVG elements are then rotated using a matrix.  The SVG element is rotated, however, now that the WebGL image dimensions have changed, the SVG element is not scaled properly for the background WebGL image.  The location of the SVG element is incorrect as well.

I know that the SVG element needs to be scaled and translated based on the new WebGL dimensions, but I'm not sure how to go about that.  I have attached the link to the image that should illustrate the issue (I couldn't post the image directly).  Thanks for any suggestions!!

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dZ6H0wO.png]

Here is the code to rotate the SVG Element.

```
var annotation = document.getElementsByTagName("line"),
    yCenter = svg.height.baseVal.value / 2,
    xCenter = svg.width.baseVal.value / 2,
    radians = 90 * (Math.PI / 180),
    cos = Math.cos(radians),
    sin = Math.sin(radians);

var pre = Matrix.create([
    [1, 0, -xCenter]
    [0, 1, -yCenter]
    [0, 0, 1]));

var rotate = Matrix.create([
    [cos, -sin, 0]
    [sin, cos, 0]
    [0, 0, 1]));

var post = Matrix.create([
    [1, 0, xCenter]
    [0, 1, yCenter]
    [0, 0, 1]));

var multipliedMatrix = post.multiple(rotate.muliple(pre);
var a = multipliedMatrix.e(1, 1),
    b = multipliedMatrix.e(2, 1),
    c = multipliedMatrix.e(1, 2),
    d = multipliedMatrix.e(2, 2),
    e = multipliedMatrix.e(1, 3),
    f = multipliedMatrix.e(2, 3);
var matrix = "matrix(" + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + ")";
annotation.setAttribute("transform", matrix);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Including the image is very helpful for others to answer your question. In addition, I would suggest providing the code you have already written to help better understand your line of thinking.

Comment: Thanks buczek, I have added the code to rotate the SVG element.